# Trying to Create a filter function for Scheme

Tags: scheme

So i have

```
(define (countNumber lats)
  (let loop ((lats2 lats)
    (count 0))(cond ((null? lats2) count)
     ((number? (car lats2)) 
      (loop (cdr lats2) (+ count 1)))
        (else (loop (cdr lats2) count)))))
```

and i want to make a filter function that goes something like

```
(define (filter func lst)
  (countNumber (filter lst)))
```

So essentially you pass in something like (filter even? '(1 2 3 4)) and it returns 2 and 4. filter: arity mismatch is the error given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `func` predicate along, and don't name your function `filter`, that clashes with a built-in procedure. Try this:

```
(define (my-filter func lst)
  (countNumber (filter func lst))
```